# How to take user input and turn it to a character for a switch statement c++

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ programming, so to both practice and take notes I am creating a project that answers very basic questions, so far it looks like this;

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>


int main()
{
        int n = 1;
        char y;

        while (n < 5)
        {

               std::cout << ("What is your question\n");
            std::string ans;
            std::cin >> ans;
            std::cout << ("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

            if (ans == "comments")
            {
                y = 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                y = 0;
            }



            switch (y)
            {
                case '1':
                    std::cout << ("\nUse // for single line comments and /* */ for multiple lines\n\n");
                    break;

        case '2':
                    std::cout << ("\nTo start add the library  #include<iostream in most cases, add more if necassary\n\n");
                    break;

        case '3':
                    std::cout << ("\nAfter the libraries are added you must initiate program by using \n int main() \n { \n\n } \n all code must fit in between the curly braces \n\n");
                    break;

        case '4':
                    std::cout << ("\nVariables hold number ");

        default:
                    std::cout << ("\ninvalid word\n\n");

        }
    std::cout << ("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");


    std::cout << ("Type 1 to repeat \nType 15 to end\n\n");
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << ("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

      }
            return 0;
}
```

The if/else statement is picking up the "comments" phrase that you enter I have tested this with a cout statement before, the issue is that it is not changing the char 'y'. It does change it when made into an int, but the switch will not pick it up, any suggestions?

Comment: `1` is *completely different* than `'1'`. Stay consistent. Look at your `if-else`. Then look at your `switch` and `case`s. Then look at the `if-else` again. See the inconsistency?

Comment: Also note the missing `break` in `case '4'`. Was that intentional?

Comment: That worked well, I never noticed that, thank you for helping me